# Where is PhantomJS localstorage and WebSQL located on Windows?

Tags: windows, phantomjs

Where do I find PhantomJS' localstorage and WebSQL data on Windows? I'm unable to create new databases with Phantom's WebSQL, so I suspect it might have run out of space. To remedy the situation I mean to delete its localstorage and WebSQL data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data is located in `%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Ofi Labs\PhantomJS`. Not sure exactly which files correspond to what, but there were a number of .db files in there. Incidentally, deleting the directory solved my problem.

Comment: Not really related to the question, but in case someone's googling this (like me) and trying to find the location on mac: /Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/Ofi Labs/PhantomJS

Comment: My localStorage elements were corrupted, so deleting the files in PhantomJS resolved it for me. Thanks for giving me the location. 

P.s. I'm using both Mac and Windows, so thanks @RoyS !

Comment: On linux I found it at `~/.qws/share/data/Ofi\ Labs/PhantomJS`